# gRPC C# DNS Resolution Failed - Domain name not found

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, grpc, .net-6.0

i got the issue that, when i want to connect to any of my grpc services. This started happening yesterday out of nowhere. (i did not change anything neither in the code nor the os).

This is the Error Message:

```
Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="DNS resolution failed for https://0.0.0.0:3000: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=https://0.0.0.0:3000 is_balancer=0: Domain name not found"
```

All the Services get the Host/Port from a Config File, that has a scheme like this:

```json
{
    "Services": {
        "Common": {
            "SSL": {
                "UseSSL": true,
                "CertificateChain": "server.crt",
                "PrivateKey": "server.pem"          
            }
        },
        "GrpcService": {
            "Hostname": "0.0.0.0",
            "Port": 3000
        },
    }
}
```

Each Server/Client has a Constructor that fetches the Configuration and (if necessary) configures ssl/https:
Server:

```cs
var host = config.GetValue<string>("Services:CameraIO:Hostname");
var port = config.GetValue<int>("Services:CameraIO:Port");
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        Server server;
        if (config.GetValue<bool>("Services:Common:SSL:UseSSL"))
            server = new Server
            {
                Services = { CameraIOService.BindService(new CameraIOServer()) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort(host, port, Util.GetServerCertificates(config)) }
            };
        else
            server = new Server
            {
                Services = { CameraIOService.BindService(new CameraIOServer()) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort(host, port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };
        services.AddSingleton(server);
        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ServiceHost>();
    });
Console.WriteLine($"Starting RPC CameraIO Server on {host}:{port}");
hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
```

Client:

```cs
if (config.GetValue<bool>("Services:Common:SSL:UseSSL"))
{
    var sslChannel = new Channel("https://" + config.GetValue<string>("Services:CameraIO:Hostname"),
        config.GetValue<int>("Services:CameraIO:Port"),
        Util.GetClientCertificate(config));
    client = new CameraIOService.CameraIOServiceClient(sslChannel);
}
else
{
    var host = "http://" + config.GetValue<string>("Services:CameraIO:Hostname");
    var port = config.GetValue<int>("Services:CameraIO:Port");
    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress($"{host}:{port}");
    client = new CameraIOService.CameraIOServiceClient(channel);
}
logger = new LoggingClient<CameraIOClient>();
```

I do not know if this is relevant, but these are the Utility Methods to get the Client/Server SSL Credentials:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Get Server SSL Credentials
/// </summary>
/// <param name="config"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static SslServerCredentials GetServerCertificates(IConfiguration config)
{
    var ccPath = config.GetValue<string>("Services:Common:SSL:CertificateChain");
    var pkPath = config.GetValue<string>("Services:Common:SSL:PrivateKey");
    if (!File.Exists(ccPath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
            $"Could not find Certificate Chain File!\nCurrent Path: {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\nLooking for File: {ccPath}");

    if (!File.Exists(pkPath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
            $"Could not find Private Key File!\nCurrent Path: {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Looking for File: {pkPath}");
    var kcp = new KeyCertificatePair(
        File.ReadAllText(ccPath),
        File.ReadAllText(pkPath));
    return new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair> { kcp });
}

/// <summary>
/// Get Client SSL Credentials
/// </summary>
/// <param name="config"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static SslCredentials GetClientCertificate(IConfiguration config)
{
    var ccPath = config.GetValue<string>("Services:Common:SSL:CertificateChain");
    if (!File.Exists(ccPath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
            $"Could not find Certificate Chain File!\nCurrent Path: {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\nLooking for File: {ccPath}");
    return new SslCredentials(
        File.ReadAllText(ccPath));
}
```

This is my `Main.cs`-File (Main Method)

```cs
if (File.Exists("imgui.ini")) File.Delete("imgui.ini");
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("settings.json").AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
var loggingService = new LoggingServerHost(config);
var cameraIOService = new CameraIOServerHost(config);
var metricServer = new MetricServerHost(config);
var gui = new CoreGUI.CoreGui();

var lst = Task.Run(loggingService.Start);
var ciost = Task.Run(cameraIOService.Start);
var mst = Task.Run(metricServer.Start);

var metricClient = new MetricClient();

if (lst.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
    RunningServices.Add("Logging Server");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Could not start Logging Server!");

if (ciost.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
    RunningServices.Add("CameraIO Server");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Could not start CameraIO Server!");

if (mst.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
    RunningServices.Add("Metric Server");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Could not start Metric Server");

metricClient.PushMetric(new Metric
    { ServiceName = "Core", Name = "running_services", Value = string.Join(",", RunningServices) });

if (config.GetValue<bool>("Services:Core:StartUI")) gui.Start();

Console.ReadLine();
```

This Batch-Script creates the used Certificates:

```
@echo off
title Certificate Generation Script

if exist certs\ rd /q /s certs\
if exist request\ rd /q /s request\

mkdir certs
mkdir request

set OPENSSL_BIN=openssl
set EXPIRE_DAYS=7
set PASSPHRASE=password
set BIT_LENGTH=4096

set CRT_PATH=certs
set REQ_PATH=request

set CAC_SUBJ=""
set SSR_SUBJ=""

echo Generating Root Certificate Authority Key...
%OPENSSL_BIN% genrsa -passout pass:%PASSPHRASE% -des3 -out %CRT_PATH%\root.key %BIT_LENGTH%

echo Generating Root CA Certificate...
%OPENSSL_BIN% req -passin pass:%PASSPHRASE% -new -x509 -days %EXPIRE_DAYS% -key %CRT_PATH%\root.key -out %CRT_PATH%\root.crt -subj %CAC_SUBJ%

echo Generating Server Key...
%OPENSSL_BIN% genrsa -passout pass:%PASSPHRASE% -des3 -out %CRT_PATH%\server.key %BIT_LENGTH%

echo Generating Server Signing Request...
%OPENSSL_BIN% req -passin pass:%PASSPHRASE% -new -key %CRT_PATH%\server.key -out %REQ_PATH%\server.csr -subj %SSR_SUBJ%

echo Self-Signing Server Certificate...
%OPENSSL_BIN% x509 -req -passin pass:%PASSPHRASE% -days %EXPIRE_DAYS% -extensions server_ssl -extfile openssl-ext.cnf -in %REQ_PATH%\server.csr -CA %CRT_PATH%\root.crt -CAkey %CRT_PATH%\root.key -set_serial 01 -out %CRT_PATH%\server.crt

echo Removing Passphrase from Server Key...
%OPENSSL_BIN% rsa -passin pass:%PASSPHRASE% -in %CRT_PATH%\server.key -out %CRT_PATH%\server.key

echo Exporting PKCS12 Keys...
%OPENSSL_BIN% pkcs12 -export -in %CRT_PATH%\root.crt -inkey %CRT_PATH%\root.key -out %CRT_PATH%\root.pfx -passout pass:%PASSPHRASE% -passin pass:%PASSPHRASE% -name "<My Company> Root CA Certificate"
%OPENSSL_BIN% pkcs12 -export -in %CRT_PATH%\server.crt -inkey %CRT_PATH%\server.key -out %CRT_PATH%\server.pfx -passout pass:%PASSPHRASE% -passin pass:%PASSPHRASE% -name "<My Application> Self-Signed Server Certificate"

echo Generating PEM Version of Key...
type %CRT_PATH%\server.key > %CRT_PATH%\server.pem
type %CRT_PATH%\server.crt >> %CRT_PATH%\server.pem

rd /q /s request\
```

Anyone got a clue on what the problem could be?

Comment: the exception is telling you that it is a DNS problem; so... is DNS ok here? does the name resolve, from the machine that is failing?

Comment: it appears to be an issue with the SSL-Certificate (or something related to https/ssl) as everything works fine without it

Comment: Looks like the certificate script you use generates certificates that are only valid for 7 days?